# Retrieve Select-Object in variable

Tags: powershell

I have this foreach :

```
Foreach($Cert in $CertSame) {

    Foreach( $ChildCert in  Get-Childitem –path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($Cert.thumbprint)) {

        $ChildCert | Select-Object -Property Subject,@{n=’ExpireInDays’;e={($_.notafter – (Get-Date)).Days}}

    }

}
```

The return is

```
Subject        ExpireInDays
-------        ------------
CN=*.x.be           311
CN=*.x.com           74
```

I need to save the subject in a variable, and the days in another variable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I would recommend changing your comment to an answer so you can get the proper credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
$Variable = $ChildCert | Select-Object -Property Subject,@{n=’ExpireInDays’;e={($_.notafter – (Get-Date)).Days}};
$Subject = $Variable.Subject; 
$ExpireInDays = $Variable.ExpireInDays;
```